# Centering table content (images and text)

Tags: html, css

How can i center the text to be in the middle of the cell:

[table_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZfGP.png)

the html of one cell:

```
<td>
   <label for="mcoin"><img src="relics/19.png">Molten Coin</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="check" onClick="MC()" name="mcoin">
</td>
```

when i use p tags it makes the cells to wide and not centered with the img.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `vertical-align: middle` and you are good to go

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qDg4q/)

CSS

```
td img {
   vertical-align: middle;   
}
```

Comment: @user2271430 Check out my demo